# Is there a way to query size on disk of a file from cmd or powershell if the file is only a remotely available file?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive

Is there a way to query size on disk of a file from cmd or powershell if the file is only a remotely available file without having to download the file in Windows 10?

`get-itemproperty` for example will trigger download of the file. (That is assuming there is even a field in the return that corresponds to size on disk.)

Comment: There needs to be more information. Where is the file available?

Comment: @WG481: Based on the [onedrive] tag I'm assuming OP means placeholder files with "recall on access" flag, such as the ones used by Azure "tiered storage" and OneDrive "files on-demand" features.

Comment: Yes to the above. Yes highlight to onedrive tag.